# PyQt5 - Switch between multiple QMainWindows using a stacked widget

Tags: python, pyqt5

So I am making a PyQt5 game and have created different .py files using Qt Designer for a start screen, level selector, and levels. So basically all the files represent the various windows which I can open/run individually using the standard:

```
app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
Level_Window = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
ui = LevelWindow(Level_Window)
Level_Window.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Now, how can I make the actual window switching to work? I was thinking to have another py file that has a window manager class with a stacked widget containing all these other windows. Also other windows should be able to access this stacked widget to like switch to a desired window when user clicks something. Can someone explain how I can accomplish this?

Comment: Two important things. QStackedWidget normally represents a parent or top level widget: it *embeds* its pages, which means that its *child* widgets are not **ever** going to be top level widgets (aka: "windows"); QMainWindow is a class intended to be a top level window, and, as such, should *never* be a child in a layout (excluding specific exceptions, as MDI areas and Graphics Views). Then, the OOP properly instructs that child objects should **never** directly access their parents' methods ([encapsulation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-oriented_programming#Encapsulation).

Comment: So, the question here is: what is your "actual window"? From your code, it seems like you're trying to use a `pyuic` generated code in its simpler form, but a "main" window containing a QStackedWidget will actually use those files in a different way, possibly by properly using composition or (better) multiple inheritance. Is that `LevelWindow` ui one of the many pages that are supposed to be shown in the main UI?